# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mentioned_in'. (Python)

Tags: python, discord

Im coding a discord bot and I'm trying to make it so when someone mentions someone else, in this case it's midway, it sends a message. But whenever I try it, it comes up with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mentioned_in'. This is my code:

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  midway = client.get_user('midways ID goes here')
  if midway.mentioned_in(message):
    await message.channel.send('words here')





client.run(os.environ['environ'])
```

Comment: That means the function didn't return anything.  You're sure you have the ID correct?

Comment: Yeah I'm positive that the ID was correct. Did I use mentioned_in incorrectly or something?

Answer (score 0):

A `Message` object should go there to the `mentioned_in`, check out docs:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ClientUser.mentioned_in